# Firebase Firestore detach a listener doesn't work

Tags: firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I (think I) am following the [instructions on how to detach a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) in `Firebase` `Firestore`, but in my code the listener remains active.

```
// attaching a listener
this.dbTasks.where('completed', '==', true).onSnapshot(data => {...code...})

// detaching a listener
this.dbTasks.where('completed', '==', true).onSnapshot(() => {})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`onSnapshot` returns a function that you need to save in a variable and call when you want to remove the listener.

```
this.unsubscribe = this.dbTasks.where('completed', '==', true).onSnapshot(
  data => {...code...}
);


// Stop listening to changes
this.unsubscribe();
```

What you are doing is actually creating a second listener that doesn't do anything.

Comment: ahhhh thank you so much. I was extracting onSnapshot to a separate function; I could attach a listener but not detach it. I was not returning the result of the snapshot!